# Java ThreadPoolExecutor: Change Thread Termination Behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) along with a custom ThreadFactory and Thread to handle a series of tasks.  Each Thread at creation grabs a Communicator object that it holds onto for the entirety of it's existence.

My issue is that once the ThreadPoolExecutor decides to reduce its pool size and terminates a thread I need to do some cleanup of that Communicator object.

What is the best way to handle cleaning up a Thread when a ThreadPoolExecutor decides to terminate it?  Is there a function I can override?

Answer (score 0):

Since run() is only called once for each thread, you can add a finally{} block to the custom Threads run() as such...

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        super.run();
    } finally {
        cleanup();
    }
}
```

The cleanup() function will be called when the ThreadPoolExecutor terminates that thread.